# XML C# How to remove parent element if any of multiple child elements contains a value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, parent-child, element

I have an XML file that I want to match for numbers against an array of numbers that are not allowed in the XML file . If any of the childnodes contains any of the numbers in an array I want to remove the parent node.

Array:

```
int [] excluded = new int[] { 112659, 112800, 113201}
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<file>
  <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>11354</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112657</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
  <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>234</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112658</number>
    </faktura>
        <faktura>
      <number>112659</number>
    </faktura>
        <faktura>
      <number>112660</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
    <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>24202</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112661</number>
    </faktura>
        <faktura>
      <number>112662</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
</file>
```

In the example I want to remove the parent element "fakturor" where there is a child faktura with number= 112659.

I have been working on some C# code and this is as far as I have come right now.

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);

        List<string> excluded = new List<string> { "112659", "112800", "113201" };

        var allFakturor = xDoc.Descendants("fakturor");

        foreach (var parentFaktura in allFakturor)
        {
            var hasChildToBeExcluded = parentFaktura.Elements("faktura").Where(t => excluded.Contains(t.Element("number").Value));

            if (hasChildToBeExcluded.Count() > 0)
            {
                parentFaktura.Remove();
            }
        }
```

Anyone with any bright ideas? I would like to have a nice onliner. The above C# code does not really do the trick.

Thanks // R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using *linq to xml*:
1 - Search all elements that exist in `excluded` list, like the following code:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
List<string> excluded = new List<string> { "112659", "112800", "113201" };

List<XElement> elementsToRemove = xDocument.Descendants("number")
    .Where(x => excluded.Contains(x.Value))
    .ToList();
```

2 - Get the ancestors of any element in the list `elementsToRemove` and remove it:

```
foreach(XElement xElement in elementsToRemove)
{
    xElement.Ancestors("fakturor").Remove();
}
xmlDoc.Save(fileName);
```

3 - Demo:

```
Console.WriteLine(xDocument);
```

4 - Result:

```
<file>
  <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>11354</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112657</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
  <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>24202</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112661</number>
    </faktura>
    <faktura>
      <number>112662</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
</file>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: It is not clear from the OP if **number** elements that are children of **kund** element should be involved.

Comment: I think,the OP wants to remove **fakturor**, if not, will demand to remove just the parent **faktura**

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I´ve used Yitzhak Khabinsky solution and it worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

*LINQ to XML* `Contains()` method can simulate *SQL's IN* clause. It allows to use set based operations without any loops.

Check it out.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\fakturor.xml";
    const string FAKTURA = "faktura";
    const string FAKTUROR = "fakturor";

    // list of exclusion values
    List<string> listOfExcluded = new List<string> { "112659", "112800", "113201" };

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    List<XElement> nodes = xdoc.Descendants(FAKTURA).ToList();

    // Contains() simulates SQL: IN clause
    nodes.Elements()
        .Where(x => listOfExcluded.Contains(x.Value))
        .Ancestors(FAKTUROR)
        .Remove();

    Console.WriteLine(xdoc);
    xdoc.Save(fileName);
}
```

> Output

```
<file>
  <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>11354</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112657</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
  <fakturor>
    <kund>
      <number>24202</number>
    </kund>
    <faktura>
      <number>112661</number>
    </faktura>
    <faktura>
      <number>112662</number>
    </faktura>
    <sum_total_fakturor />
  </fakturor>
</file>
```